# sql make column name not duplicate and show all other value in same table

Tags: php, sql

I don't want duplicate column name of company_name and when I click collapse bootstrap it shows the table values that has the same name of company_name

[this is output now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0KdI.png)

```
 <?php 
        $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT company_name,project,po_number FROM company");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result=$stmt->get_result();
        ?>
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <?php  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>  
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" >
            <h2 class="mb-0">
            <a class="btn cat" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#c<?=$row['company_name']?>" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            <?php echo $row['company_name'] ?>
            </a>
            </h2>
          </div>
         
        <div id="c<?=$row['company_name']?>" class="collapse">
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive ">
          <table class="table table-hover table-borderless" id="table1">
            <thead>
                <tr class="text-truncate">
                    <th>Po</th>
                    <th>ชื่อโครงการ</th>
                    <th>ผู้รับผิดชอบ</th>
                    <th>รายละเอียด</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php $c;  ?>
               <tr class="<?=($c++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even' ?>">
                  <td><?php echo $row['po_number'] ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['project'] ?></td>
                  
                </tr> 
                </tbody> 
          </table>        
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      <?php  } ?>  
      </div>
      </div>
```

I want my collapse show like this hope you understand 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtwEe.png

Comment: You don't need a prepared statement,  a standard query will do.  The result set object can be iterated as if an array of associative arrays if simply fed to a `foreach()`.  Even and odd row classes (for styling purposes) can be wholly done with css and without classes. `<?php $c;  ?>` is useless.  You have too many `<th>`s and not enough `<td>`s.  `id="table1"` in a loop will generate duplicate ids in the loop -- this is invalid markup.  How is your script failing?

Comment: So how should your output be when `DISTINCT company_name,project,po_number` generates duplicate company_names because of the project and po_number values?  You want extra table body rows?  Would you like to ORDER BY company_name and skip the "card" if the current company_name is the same as the last?

Comment: @mickmackusa this can work in a standard query? and I upload the output in the post.I don't want to display the same company_name and I want po_number, project show in the same company_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it will be cleanest to create a grouped array structure from your result set, then use nested loops to generate the output from the new structure.

Suggested Code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT company_name, project, po_number FROM company";

$grouped = [];
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    $grouped[$row['company_name']][] = [
        'project' => $row['project'],
        'po_number' => $row['po_number']
    ];
}

// now generate markup...
?>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <?php foreach ($grouped as $companyName => $details) { ?>  
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <a class="btn cat" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
             href="#c<?=$companyName?>" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
          >
            <?=$companyName?>
          </a>
        </h2>
      </div>
         
      <div id="c<?=$companyName?>" class="collapse">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover table-borderless">
              <thead>
                <tr class="text-truncate">
                  <th>Po</th>
                  <th>ชื่อโครงการ</th>
                  <th>ผู้รับผิดชอบ</th>
                  <th>รายละเอียด</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($details as $i => $detail) { ?>
                  <tr class="<?=$i & 1?'odd':'even'=>">
                    <td><?=$detail['po_number']?></td>
                    <td><?=$detail['project']?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                <?php } ?>
              </tbody> 
            </table>        
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php  } ?>  
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that work for me perfectly never do this before I gonna read the code how it work